# Integrating Cocos2D with UIKit

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit, cocos2d-iphone

I've looked around, and i've seen very little material on how to integrate cocos2d with UIKit (note: not the other way around). What i mean is... for example... adding a cocos sprite animation inside a UIView, which is placed inside a split-view controller (as a subview). How can i do that!?

I want to start with a UISplitView project template or the UITabBar project template.

p.s. I've been doing iPhone development for a while now, but i'm a noob when it comes to cocos2d framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a demo in Cocos2d called `AttachDemo`, where it attaches a Cocos2d director to a `UIView`. If you check the method called `-(void)runCocos2d`.

If you look at its code, it does the following:

```
-(void) runCocos2d
{
    if( state == kStateEnd ) {

        EAGLView *glview = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250,350)];
        [mainView addSubview:glview];

        CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
        [director setOpenGLView:glview];

        CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
        id node = [LayerExample node];
        [scene addChild: node];

        [director runWithScene:scene];

        state = kStateRun;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"End the view before running it");
    }
}
```

As you can see, you need to create a `EAGLView`, attach a director to it, and then simply add that view to the view hierarchy.

Comment: Great! But, what if i'm in a tabBar controller and each controller contains an EAGLView, or i have multiple EAGLViews inside my UIView? Does the director keep a record of ALL the views? And, can i run some of the scenes and stop others? Thanks.

Comment: What you can do, is after switching to another tab, call `[director setOpenGLView:glview];` on the tab's main view, and set the scene there. You'll use several `EAGLView`s but only one `CCDirector`.

Comment: do you have a link to this demo? i can't seem to find it

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link of the demo @pgb is referring to, http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/source/browse/trunk/tests/attachDemo/attachDemo.m?r=1682