# Cocos 2D in UIKit application?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have pretty much made my app to about 90% using UIKit code since it is my first app and wanted to keep it simple. Now I learned that I needed to use Cocos 2D in one of my views, my play view. So I have coded half of the functionality in the view using UIKit. Is there any way to use Cocos 2D in that view for the actual game part? Are there any **easy** tutorials or links someone can point me to, to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrating Cocos2D with UIKit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566055/integrating-cocos2d-with-uikit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the link Brad noted is a great reference.  More immediately something like....

```
EAGLView *glview = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250,350)];
[yourView addSubview:glview];

CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[director setOpenGLView:glview];
```

Should work for you.  Create the OpenGL view for the CCDirector to use.  Attach that view as a subview of the view where you want it placed.  Attach the CCDirector to your OpenGL view.

Additionally the Cocos2D website and wiki have some great resources that may help...

- Cococs2D Wiki  - http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/
- Cocos2D Forums - http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/

Comment: thanks! At this point I am just trying to get the Cocos2D files into my project. What files should I drag into my project and from where? Please be specific as I am having issues with this, thanks!!!