# Integrating MapKit with Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, mapkit, integration, ccuiviewwrapper

I'm a bit new with MapKit and have been trying to find the answer to this question:

Can I integrate, or to what extent can I integrate MapKit with Cocos2d?

In having this question answered, I hope that somebody could point me in the right direction on how to approach this scenario:
I am developing a Cocos2D app in which one part of the app would be the MapKit application, showing location and annotations (basically everything that comes with MapKit), and the user has the option to switch to the Cocos2D part. (Switching back and forth between the Map and the Game).

If the two were integrated, would there then be a way to overlay a Cocos2D Menu system over the MapKit and treat MapKit as simply a CCLayer or CCNode? or do I need to treat these two as separate entities altogether by only using UIKit buttons and menus with MapKit, and the only real mix between them is the passing of data from MapKit on to Cocos2D view on transition and vice versa?

Would it follow the same concept as integrating UIKit and Cocos2D in [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566055/integrating-cocos2d-with-uikit) or this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit)? Or do I have to use a special wrapper class such as [CCUIViewWrapper](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889)? I read that CCUIViewWrapper is always drawn on top, so it could possibly not allow me to draw a Cocos2D Menu on top of the map, or even overlay a Cocos2D object once a UIKit button is pressed in the MapKit App.

Any help would be appreciated...Thanks!

Comment: I have same problem.. So If you have any solution please let me know.. thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think using CCUIViewWrapper will be a good idea, about the question that CCUIViewWrapper always draw on the topmost layer of View I think that is kinda wrong(I am not sure) as CCUIViewWrapper returns the object in the format of CCNode so you can add it anywhere on the screen you would like to (If I was in your place I would have first tested this with adding a small sprite on top of a MapKit View in a cocos2d project just to be sure).

-Ankur

Comment: Hi Ankur. Yes I understand that trying it out first would be best, but since I had these different methods of doing it, I wanted to see if someone else knew which one I should follow first since I don't exactly have that much free time to do trial-error right now. The reason I said I can't put anything above CCUIViewWrapper is because of this post: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/21020 . Seeing it, I didn't think CCUIViewWrapper would be the solution...so idk, maybe I'll test it later when I have the time..